# How to avoid auto sorts in F# Seq.map

Tags: f#

**Seq.map** returns a sorted pair but I don't need it.Is there any way to avoid sorting of map on the basis of key value. I want to display all pair in same order i insert it into map.

Comment: Maps (as Sets) are immutable unordered collections based on binary trees, this is why they're sorted by keys. To avoid sorting the entries, you can use a mutable System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary.

Comment: Just use a list.

Comment: Thanks a lot , I will try

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-collections-mapmodule.html#toSeq), F# `Map.toSeq` will return all map entries ordered by the keys. If you want to iterate through items in the order in which they were added, then `Map` is not appropriate. You will need a different data-structure.

One option is to use a `list`:

```ml
let xs =
  []
  |> fun xs -> (1, "a") :: xs
  |> fun xs -> (2, "b") :: xs
  |> fun xs -> (7, "x") :: xs
  |> fun xs -> (3, "c") :: xs

for x in List.rev xs do
  printfn $"%A{x}"

// (1, "a")
// (2, "b")
// (7, "x")
// (3, "c")
```

Note that the items are iterated in *reverse order*, so `List.rev` is required to obtain the original order.

Since you are using `Map`, it seems like you want to maintain only one value for each key. This can be done using a custom type.

```ml
type OrderPreservingMap<'k, 'v when 'k : comparison> =
  {
    Items : Map<'k, 'v>

    // Track when keys were inserted, with the most recent first
    Insertions : 'k list
  }

module OrderPreservingMap =

  let empty<'k, 'v when 'k : comparison> : OrderPreservingMap<'k, 'v> =
    {
      Items = Map.empty
      Insertions = []
    }

  let add (k : 'k) (v : 'v) (m : OrderPreservingMap<'k, 'v>) =
    if Map.containsKey k m.Items then
      {
        Items = Map.add k v m.Items
        Insertions = k :: (m.Insertions |> List.except [ k ])
      }
    else
      {
        Items = Map.add k v m.Items
        Insertions = k :: m.Insertions
      }

  let toSeq (m : OrderPreservingMap<'k, 'v>) =
    m.Insertions
    |> List.rev
    |> Seq.map
      (fun k -> k, Map.find k m.Items)
```

Usage:

```ml
let xs =
  OrderPreservingMap.empty
  |> OrderPreservingMap.add 1 "a"
  |> OrderPreservingMap.add 2 "b"
  |> OrderPreservingMap.add 7 "x"
  |> OrderPreservingMap.add 3 "c"

for x in OrderPreservingMap.toSeq xs do
  printfn $"%A{x}"

// (1, "a")
// (2, "b")
// (7, "x")
// (3, "c")
```